# Joining 2 Oracle tables using Join in SSIS

Tags: oracle, join, ssis, attunity

I have to get data from database1 something like

```
select *
from tab1
where dtCol > <*dtVariable*>
```

The value of *dtVariable* comes from database2 from

```
select *
processdt
where proc_name = 'PROCESS1'
```

Can you please let me how to do this?

```
I am using SSIS 2008
Oracle db - 12c
Oracle Drivers - Attunity 1.2
```

No DBLInks ( basically, we need to avoid using db links)

Comment: is there a dblink from database1 to database2? (`select * from all_DB_LINKS`) or a (1/2) linked server to the oracle databases in SSIS?  If DB link.... `SELECT * from tab1 where dtcol > (Select DTvariable  from processdt@database2 where proc_name = 'PROCESS1')` assuming dtvariable is column name and proc_name of process will result in a single value.

Comment: No Dblinks.. All this is to avoid dblinks and Materialized views..

Answer (score 0):

You would simply need to pull the input value from Db2 to a variable in SSIS as step 1.
Step 2, you would create an expression that forms that SELECT sql call encompassing that variable.
MSDN has an article how to use [Execute SQL Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/execute-sql-task).

Comment: Sorry to ask.. Being a novice to SSIS, Can you please give some steps how to do this?

Comment: Hi @RasKnorr added the link to the official documentation. You can find more in various blog posts on this topic.